# Fail to `JSON.stringify(this)` when learning OOP (got RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded)

Tags: javascript, oop, stack-overflow

```
function MyClass() {
    this.foo = "foo";
    this.bar = "bar";
}

MyClass.prototype.toJSON = function(space) {
    if (typeof space === 'undefined') space = 4;
    return JSON.stringify(this, null, space);
};

var m = new MyClass();
console.log(m.toJSON());
```

I ran it in node.js, and got:

```
MyClass.prototype.toJSON = function(space) {
                                   ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I don't know why. It makes me confused. Could you please tell me the reason causing this error? And how to fix it?

Comment: `this` in your `.toJSON` method is a reference to `m` and `stringify` will invoke a `.toJSON` method if it exists on the data it's given. So `m.toJSON()` calls `JSON.stringify(m...`, which calls `m.toJSON()`, which calls `JSON.stringify(m...`, and so on.

Comment: That's the answer `cookie monster`, not just a comment. Here's a comment: You should change `if (typeof space === 'undefined') space = 4;` to `var spc = space ? space : 4;`. Then pass `spc` to `JSON.stringify()`, as the last argument.

Comment: Note that reassigning the argument creates potential scope issues. In this case `space` could assign a global variable.

Comment: @PHPglue: Don't worry about posting an answer that was already given as a comment. If a person (like me) decides to use a comment to answer the question, that's their (my) problem. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this by renaming the `.toJSON` function to `.save`.

I found the reason here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify, which says:

> If an object being stringified has a property named toJSON whose value is a function, then the toJSON method customizes JSON stringification behavior: instead of the object being serialized, the value returned by the toJSON method when called will be serialized.

So the original code would cause an infinite recursive.

Thanks to *@cookie monster* and *@PHPglue*.

Working code:

```
function MyClass() {
    this.foo = "foo";
    this.bar = "bar";
}

MyClass.prototype.save = function(space) {
    var s = typeof space === 'undefined' ? 0 : 4;
    return JSON.stringify(this, null, s);
};

var m = new MyClass();
console.log(m.save());
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it helped in 2023 NodeJS project that was reporting a stack size error due to the recursive calling of a class that has a toJSON() function. MacOS and Windows didn't exhibit this behavior, but it was happening on a Linux server.

Answer (score 0):

`@cookie monster` really answered the question, maybe this will help though:

```
function MyClass(){
  this.foo = 'foo';
  this.bar = 'bar';
  this.gotToJSON = false;
}

MyClass.prototype.toJSON = function(space){
  var spc = space ? space : 4;
  if(!this.gotToJSON){
    this.gotToJSON = true;
    var result = JSON.stringify(this, null, spc);
    this.gotToJSON = false;
    return result;
  }
  return;
}

var m = new MyClass;
console.log(m.toJSON());
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing Name

> .toJSON

to something else like **displayJSON** works for me